# C++ undefined references to functions in namespace

Tags: c++, c, function, namespaces

This has been bothering me for awhile. I have a namespace, and in that namespace I want to declare C-style functions. So I did what I thought was right:

```
namespace test
{
    std::deque<unsigned> CSV_TO_DEQUE(const char* data);
    std::deque<unsigned> ZLIB64_TO_DEQUE(const char* data, int width, int height);

    std::string BASE64_DECODE(std::string const& encoded_string);
}
```

Then for the implementation file:

```
#include "theheaderfile.hpp"

using namespace test;

std::deque<unsigned> CSV_TO_DEQUE(const char* data)
{
     ...
}
std::deque<unsigned> ZLIB64_TO_DEQUE(const char* data, int width, int height)
{
     ...
}

std::string BASE64_DECODE(std::string const& encoded_string)
{
     ...
}
```

However, when trying to actually call the functions, I get an undefined reference error. The file links, so I'm not sure why the references are undefined.

I should also add that if I take the functions out of the `test` namespace and leave them in the global namespace, they work without a hitch.

I want to avoid defining the functions within the header. Is this possible?

Comment: c file is added to the project?

Comment: You are just defining a new function with a somewhat similar name. You need to actually define them in the namespace, either by wrapping the definitions with the namespace like in the header file, or by qualifying the names `std::deque<unsigned> test::CSV_TO_DEQUE(const char* data){/...}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`using namespace` will only import the namespace for use - it won't let you define the functions in that namespace.

You still need to define the functions inside the test namespace:

```
namespace test {
    // your functions
};
```

Answer (score 6):

define it like:

```
std::deque<unsigned> test::CSV_TO_DEQUE(const char* data)
{
     ...
}
```

otherwise this is just a new function in global namespace